# get column name that matches specific row value in dataframe

Tags: r

I am trying to get the column name of each row where the cell value is 1. My attempt did not work however, can anyone offer suggestions?

```
library(permute)
set.seed(42)
exampledf<- data.frame(allPerms(c(1,2,3,4)))
exampledf<-head(exampledf)
```

I tried this:

```
apply(exampledf,2,function(x){
    ll<-x[1]==1
    which(ll==T)
    })
```

Dataset

```
  X1 X2 X3 X4
1  1  2  4  3
2  1  3  2  4
3  1  3  4  2
4  1  4  2  3
5  1  4  3  2
6  2  1  3  4
```

My goal:

```
X1
X1
X1
X1
X1
X2
```

Comment: Try something like `names(exampledf)[max.col(exampledf == 1)]`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

this is one method:

```
# construct sample data.frame
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(matrix(
                 c(sample(1:4, 4), sample(1:4, 4), 
                   sample(1:4, 4), sample(1:4, 4)), 
                 ncol=4, byrow=T))
# name data.frame
names(df) <- c(paste0("x", 1:4))

# get names of variables
names(df)[apply(df, 1, function(i) which(i == 1))]
```

A method suggested by @DavidArenburg that is probably faster (especially for large datasets) is

```
names(df)[which(df == 1, arr.ind=T)[, "col"]]
```

because it does not need to use the `apply` function.

Note: I constructed a different data.frame as I don't have the permute package.

Comment: You don't need to run `apply` in order to use `which`. Just `names(df)[which(df == 1, arr.ind = TRUE)[, "col"]]` will do.

Comment: The `which ... [, "col"]` version will return results in the order of the columns. This is no problem for the example given, but if the first row was `4, 3, 2, 1`, the result would be returned as `X1, X1, X1, X1, X2, X4`. An intermediate step is necessary to sort the output of `which` by its `"row"` column.

Answer (score 2):

I hope I get your question right (shouldn't the last matched column be X2 instead of X3?). Bit old school but if I get you right, this should do it.

```
library(permute)
set.seed(42)
exampledf <- data.frame(allPerms(c(1,2,3,4)))
exampledf <- head(exampledf)

matched_cols = c()
for(i in 1:nrow(exampledf)){
    row <- edf[i, ] == 1
    matched_col <- colnames(exampledf)[row == T] 
    matched_cols = c(matched_cols, matched_col)  
}
matched_cols
```

Comment: It is usually a good idea to avoid growing objects in R or in any other language. When you know the size of the object that you want to fill (here equal to the number of rows of the data frame), it is much better to pre-allocate a vector of that size to store the data. below `exampledf <- head...` you should initialize your matched_cols vector: `matched_cols <- integer(nrow(exampledf))`. You can then fill in matched_cols using `matched_cols[i] <- ...` and save R the effort of having to repeatedly copy matched_cols for each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple method :

```
library(permute)
set.seed(42)
exampledf<- data.frame(allPerms(c(1,2,3,4)))

for(i in 1:nrow(exampledf)){
    for (j in 1:length(exampledf[i,])){
        if(exampledf[i,j]==1){
           print(names(exampledf)[j])
        }
    }
}
```

The sample output is:

"X1"

"X1"

"X1"

"X1"

"X1"

"X2"

"X2"

"X3"

Answer (score -1):

In case the data frame has got multiple values of 1 in these columns it can be achieved using this, though it will one for one value as well

```
exampledf$results<-c() # Adding one empty column called results here 
for(i in (1:nrow(exampledf))){
    exampledf$results[i] <- paste((colnames(exampledf)[which(exampledf[i,1:(ncol(exampledf)-1)] ==  1)]),collapse = ",")
}
```

hopefully it would be helpful to this thread

Comment: Sorry about the typo i wanted all the values greater than 1 to be printed