# R dataframe - Top n values in row with column names

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, top-n

I want to sort rowwise values in specific columns, get top 'n' values, and get corresponding column names in new columns.

The **output** would look something like this:

```
      SL   SW    PL    PW   Species high1 high2 high3 col1 col2  col3
      dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <fct>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
 1     5.1  3.5  1.4    0.2   setosa   3.5  1.4   0.2  SW   PL     PW
 2     4.9  3    1.4    0.2   setosa   3    1.4   0.2  SW   PL     PW
 3     4.7  3.2  1.3    0.2   setosa   3.2  1.3   0.2  SW   PL     PW
```

Tried something like code below, but unable to get column names.
What I'm hoping to achieve is to compare the highest 'n' values (rows[n]) with values in dataframe for each row, and then extract corresponding column name of matching value. For eg. rows[1] == 3.5 (from column 'SW'). Is this feasible?
Help appreciated.

```
 iris %>% 
      rowwise() %>%
      mutate(rows = list(sort(c( Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width), decreasing = TRUE))) %>%
      mutate(high1 = rows[1], col1 = names(~.)[which(~.[] ==rows[1]),
             high2 = rows[2], col2 = names(~.)[which(~.[] ==rows[2]),
             high3 = rows[3], col3 = names(~.)[which(~.[] ==rows[3])
             ) %>%
      select(-rows)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was hoping to use the solution at link below with some modification. Something like names(df)[which(df == 1, arr.ind=T)[, "col"]]. Possible? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36960010/get-column-name-that-matches-specific-row-value-in-dataframe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could pivot to long, group by the corresponding original row, use `slice_max` to get the top values, then pivot back to wide and bind that output to the original table.

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(tidyr)

iris %>% 
  group_by(rn = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(Species, rn), 'col', values_to = 'high') %>% 
  slice_max(col, n = 2) %>% 
  mutate(nm = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(values_from = c(high, col), 
              names_from = nm) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-c(Species, rn)) %>% 
  bind_cols(iris)
#> # A tibble: 150 × 9
#>    high_1 high_2 col_1   col_2 Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#>     <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>   <chr>        <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>
#>  1    5.1    3.5 Sepal.… Sepa…          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2
#>  2    4.9    3   Sepal.… Sepa…          4.9         3            1.4         0.2
#>  3    4.7    3.2 Sepal.… Sepa…          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2
#>  4    4.6    3.1 Sepal.… Sepa…          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2
#>  5    5      3.6 Sepal.… Sepa…          5           3.6          1.4         0.2
#>  6    5.4    3.9 Sepal.… Sepa…          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4
#>  7    4.6    3.4 Sepal.… Sepa…          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3
#>  8    5      3.4 Sepal.… Sepa…          5           3.4          1.5         0.2
#>  9    4.4    2.9 Sepal.… Sepa…          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2
#> 10    4.9    3.1 Sepal.… Sepa…          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1
#> # … with 140 more rows, and 1 more variable: Species <fct>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Edited to remove the unnecessary `rename` and `mutate`, thanks to tip from @Onyambu!

Comment: I feel we think the same. If there were more votes, i would have voted more than once hahhaaha

Comment: Yeah the groups are maintained

Answer (score 1):

My approach is to make a function that takes any dataframe (`df`), any set of columns that you want to focus on (`cols`), and any value for top n (`n`)

```
# load data.table and magrittr (I only use %>% for illustration here)
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)

# define function
get_high_vals_cols <- function(df, cols, n=3) {
  
  setDT(df)[, `_rowid`:=.I]
  
  df_l <- melt(df,id = "_rowid",measure.vars = cols, variable.name = "col",value.name = "high") %>% 
    .[order(-high), .SD[1:n], by="_rowid"] %>% 
    .[,id:=1:.N, by="_rowid"]
  
  dcast(df_l, `_rowid`~id, value.var = list("col", "high"))[,`_rowid`:=NULL]
}
```

Then, you can feed any dataframe to this function, along with any columns of interest

```
cols= c("Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width")
get_high_vals_cols(iris,cols,3)
```

Output

```
            col_1        col_2       col_3 high_1 high_2 high_3
  1:  Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    3.5    1.4    0.2
  2:  Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    3.0    1.4    0.2
  3:  Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    3.2    1.3    0.2
  4:  Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    3.1    1.5    0.2
  5:  Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    3.6    1.4    0.2
 ---                                                           
146: Petal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Width    5.2    3.0    2.3
147: Petal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Width    5.0    2.5    1.9
148: Petal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Width    5.2    3.0    2.0
149: Petal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Width    5.4    3.4    2.3
150: Petal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Width    5.1    3.0    1.8
```